# JDBC Batch executing extremely slow

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, batch-insert

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong I'm executing 350 inserts in a mysql and it's taking like 40 secs.

Here is the code

```
long t0 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Connection con = connectionProvider.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement s = con.prepareStatement("insert into domkee.friends(idFriends,friend1Id,friend2Id,friend2Name) values(?,?,?,?)");
        con.setAutoCommit(false);
        for (Friend f : friends) {
            s.setLong(1, 0);
            s.setLong(2, f.getFriend1Id());
            s.setLong(3, f.getFriend2Id());
            s.setString(4, f.getFriend2Name());
            s.addBatch();

        }
        long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis() - t0;
        s.executeBatch();
        long t2 = System.currentTimeMillis()-t0;
        con.commit();
        long t3 = System.currentTimeMillis()-t0;
        s.close();
        con.close();
        long t4 = System.currentTimeMillis()-t0;
        System.out.println(((double)t1/1000) + ";" + ((double)t2/1000) + ";" + ((double)t3/1000) + ";" + ((double)t4/1000));
```

and here is the console:

```
0.156;39.251;39.376;39.486
```

So the `.executeBatch()` is taking like 40 secs, what could be the problem?

Comment: how much time does it take to run it vi a CLI or using a tool ?

Comment: Well from MySQL Workbench it takes about the same (39-42 secs). In case it's relevant the server is a MySQL 5 running on a small instance in AWS

Comment: So I dont think its anything to do with JAVA, I think your server is slow.

Comment: Maybe your constraints are causing it to take a long time? Have you run Explain and then your query?

Comment: So you are saying it's a hardware thing? Is there any way I can make it faster?

Comment: @Hiro2k, isn't EXPLAIN only for SELECT statements?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/explain.html
Apparently only in the newest versions of MySQL :(

Comment: @Woojah Yes since the mysql workbench also takes about the same time its something to do with the hardware. To make it faster increase the RAM of the server or something

Comment: @sheldonCooper, it says that a small instance (like mine) has the following:

Small DB Instance: 1.7 GB memory, 1 ECU (1 virtual core with 1 ECU), 64-bit platform, Moderate I/O Capacity. It shouldn't be that slow, or am I mistaken?

Comment: @Woojah Firstly how often do you do these inserts ? and why 40 inserts at a time ? Isnt there any alternative ?

Comment: Micro instances on EC2 are usually CPU throttled. Run `top`, and it might give a hint as to whether mysql is CPU bound or not. Not sure if your small instance is micro instance, or a standard instance.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Add `?rewriteBatchedStatements=true` to the end of your JDBC url. It'll give you a serious performance improvement. Note that this is specific to MySql, won't have any effect with any other JDBC drivers.

Comment: more details http://slava-technical.blogspot.com/2010/07/mysql-batch-queries-processing.html

Comment: The above suggestion is fantastic

Comment: @jtahlborn That blog is for invite only readers. Please fix it. Or make it open.

Comment: @Sibidharan i don't control the blog post.  there's plenty of other places on the web with more details.

Comment: hi , I Tried using this solution with ORacle, Not able to use. Please help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46969005/how-to-use-rewritebatchedstatements-true-with-jdbc-and-oracle

Comment: Yes, the rewriteBatchedStatements parameter is  MySql - specific, won't work with any other JDBC driver's.

Comment: Amazing! Almost 75x faster for me!