# Sybase ASE 15.5 : a successful insert which has no effect

Tags: sql, database, sybase, sap-ase

I'm trying to insert a row into a table which is quite big (400 million rows). The table has 3 columns `(integer, varchar(128),varchar(255)), primary key` and `clustered index` on columns (1,2) and `nonclustered index` on columns (2,1) and nonclustered index on column 3. No foreign keys, no triggers.

When I do :

```
insert into mytable values (0,'test_name','test_val')
```

It executes successfully but it has no effect, nothing is inserted and I can re-execute it as many times as I want successfully whereas it should say "duplicate key".

What could be the issue?

Note : noexec is off and manual commit does not change anything.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have the `ignore_dup_key` [option](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32300.1570/html/sqlug/X65321.htm) on one of the indexes. Check the results of `sp_help` procedure to see all the options that you are using for indexes.

Comment: Maybe. I will check that. But what about the rows not being inserted?

Comment: That is the behavior of this option. It skips the rows and does not insert them.

Comment: There was no such setting on any index. I gave up on this issue and reloaded a fresh dump. The issue disappeared.

Comment: If the problem still existed you could try to check the @@trancount setting - maybe somehow you have created earlier another level of transaction. Also another hint would be to select @@rowcound and @@tranchained

Answer (score 0):

based on the documentation , if `ignore_dup_key` was the culprit, you should get an error message when it cancels your insert .. you need to provide more details with your questions , like error log information , how do you insert the row .. etc.
Here's what the documentation says regarding the index option mentioned in the previous answer :

> When you begin data entry, any attempt to insert a duplicate key is canceled **with an error message.**

Comment: If ignore_dup_key kicks in, you do not get an error, but a warning 'duplicate key ignored', and the transaction continues ( in this case there is only 1 row, so it is completed)

Comment: Another possible (though a bit far-fetched) explanation is that there is trigger on the table that somehow removes the inserted row.